# Working with Python dict/list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there a better way of doing the following in Python 2.4?

```
if id in id_dict:
    id_dict[id].append(skill)
else:
    id_dict[id] = [skill]
```

Comment: Please upgrade from 2.4...

Comment: Python 2.4 is almost a decade old.

Comment: defaultdict doesn't exist in 2.4, but there are pure python implementations that will work e.g. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/523034-emulate-collectionsdefaultdict . then just declare `id_dict = defaultdict(list)` . then you can just do `id_dict[id].append(skill)` and it will automatically create a list if one doesn't exist.

Comment: Why are you using 2.4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `id` is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert `id` with a value of `[]` and return `[]`.

```
id_dict.setdefault(id, []).append(skill)
```